# Get buffer with all macros expanded in org-mode

Tags: emacs, macros, org-mode

I'm trying to troubleshoot some macro expansions in my org-mode file, how to I get a buffer that is the org-source with all org-mode macros expanded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export to org-mode, and this will generate an org-mode file with expanded macros, included files, removed comments, and all other pre-processing.

Export to org-mode buffer is bound to `C-c C-e O O`.

Comment: `C-c C-e o` is mapped to OpenDocument for me -- do you know what command that key combination is bound to?

Comment: Small `o` is OpenDocument; big `O` is org-mode export. You may have to customize `org-export-backends` in order to enable org-mode export.

Comment: Big `O` is OpenDocument + open that file (at least for me) -- it's not really useful since it opens the OpenDocument in an emacs buffer.

Comment: I'm using org-mode 8.2.6. Maybe that's the difference with your case.